# a condition on onSubmit to send email with emailjs in type script only when a react-hook-form have no erros?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form, react-tsx

I'm new in the typescript and react world. I've created a very simple form with a name and e-mail fields  using react-hook-form

Here is my code for the onSubmit and handleSubmit

```
const { register, handleSubmit, watch, formState: { errors } } = useForm<Inputs>();
const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<Inputs> = data => console.log(data);
```

I have this function to send email,

```
function sendEmail (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>){
            e.preventDefault();
            emailjs.sendForm('Your_service_id', 'your_template_id',e.currentTarget, 'Your_user_id')
            .then(function(response) {
              console.log('SUCCESS!', response.status, response.text);
            }, function(error) {
              console.log('FAILED...', error);
            });
            
      }
```

When i write

```
<form action="#" method="POST" className="space-y-6" onSubmit={sendEmail} >
 --
 --
</form>
```

or

```
 <form action="#" method="POST" className="space-y-6" onSubmit={  handleSubmit(onSubmit)} >
 --
 --
</form>
```

everything is working fine

But when I write something like that :

```
   <form action="#" method="POST" className="space-y-6" onSubmit={ () => {sendEmail; handleSubmit(onSubmit);}} >
     --
     --
   </form>
```

then nothing works

I'm struggling to implement a condition in order to send the email only when there is no errors in the react-hook form. If someone can help me out i'd be grateful.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

onSubmit get one function, if you want to write a conditional function in handleSubmit, write like:

```
<form action="#" method="POST" className="space-y-6" onSubmit={handleSubmit(yourCondition ? onSubmit:sendEmail)} >
 --
 --
 </form>
```

or you can write single function for handleSubmit:

```
    <form action="#" method="POST" className="space-y-6" onSubmit={handleSubmit(yourFunction)} > // example: onSubmit
 --
 --
 </form>
```